# Hadoop mapreduce execution stuck

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I'm using HADOOP on a VM. When I try to run a jar, the execution stops because is unable to find the file resource-type.xml.

How can I solve this? Thank you.

```
gaia@gaia-virtual-machine:~/hadoop-3.3.2$ bin/hadoop jar erasmus-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar erasmus.MaxPartecipants input output
2022-05-09 10:27:30,069 INFO client.DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2022-05-09 10:27:30,439 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
2022-05-09 10:27:30,457 INFO mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Disabling Erasure Coding for path: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/gaia/.staging/job_1652083747035_0002
2022-05-09 10:27:30,673 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2022-05-09 10:27:31,158 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
2022-05-09 10:27:31,268 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1652083747035_0002
2022-05-09 10:27:31,268 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []
2022-05-09 10:27:31,439 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
2022-05-09 10:27:31,440 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
2022-05-09 10:27:31,516 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1652083747035_0002
2022-05-09 10:27:31,553 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://gaia-virtual-machine:8088/proxy/application_1652083747035_0002/
2022-05-09 10:27:31,554 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1652083747035_0002
```

The following is the output of the jps command:

```
gaia@gaia-virtual-machine:~/hadoop-3.3.2$ jps
14998 SecondaryNameNode
14648 NameNode
14779 DataNode
17836 Jps
16780 ResourceManager
```

In the yarn web UI it says that: Total Resource Preempted:  <memory:0, vCores:0>
And in the node sections it says that there are 0 active nodes

Comment: What happens when you try to start a nodemanager to get an active node with resources?

Comment: When I restart the service my VM crashes

Comment: Is there any logs saying why it crashed? Maybe you should give the VM more memory?

Comment: Yes, I solved the issues. I had problem both with my hard disk and my ram. Tyvm!